# Implement allowsInlineMediaPlayback and "Back" button in WebView Swift

Tags: swift, webview

I want to set allowsInlineMediaPlayback in WebView to true and still have a back button, but it does not work.
With the following program I can get the video to play inline, but the back button does not work.
I don't think there is anything in the webView.goBack() webView.
What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

```
// WebView.swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var urlString: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        config.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        let webView =  WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    
    // Back button
    func goBack() {
        webView.goBack()
    }
}


// ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
private var webView = WebView(urlString: "https://hogehoge123.jp/")

var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        webView
        
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                webView.goBack()
            }, label: {
                Text("Back")
            })
        }
    }
}
```